# asp.net web service "page not found" after invoking method

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis, asmx

We have created a .NET 4 web service, which runs fine on a **Windows 7 development** pc. But now we have moved it to a **Windows 2008 standard server** which runs IIS.

When we browse to the **.asmx** file we get the correct pages that show us the available web service methods, but when we try to invoke a method by using the provide test buttons, we get a "Page not found" error.

Any suggestions on what setting / config line we should change?

I guess, because we don't get a real (yellow background, red text) asp.net error, this has something to do with IIS not picking up the request when invoking a method?

Comment: Did you know that ASMX is a legacy technology that shouldn't be used for new development? You should be using WCF for new development.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It turns out that the friendly error message option in Internet Explorer kept us busy for a while. After turning of this developer-unfriendly-feature, we were able to move on with the real problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
<webServices>
     <protocols>
       <add name="HttpGet"/>
       <add name="HttpPost"/>
     </protocols>
</webServices>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it a 404 or a 404.3? - reason being that a 404.3 Page Not Found can be returned if IIS 7 is not configured with the correct mime type handler for the response. In this case, it would be odd, but worth checking (i.e., run aspnet_regiis -i from the .net dir) to make sure that there is a mapping for XML (or whatever you're returning) responses

Comment: In the details below the 'Friendly error page/description' we see a 500 error. And, yes, we already tried to run the aspnet_regiis. But that didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Do you see a 500 error, or a page not found? They're different things.

Comment: I'll upload a screenshot tomorrow, so you can see what we see.